# QGIS clipper tool misaliagnment

Tags: qgis, gdalwarp, resampling

I'm using QGIS 2.14 and GDAL 1.11.3 and I'm running into a weird error with the clipped outputs.  I created a shapefile in QGIS and used it to clip my image.  Here's a simplified version of the command the `Clipper` plugin generates:

```
gdalwarp -q 
         -cutline ${TESTDIR}/shapefile.shp 
         -crop_to_cutline 
         -tr 5.0 5.0 
         -of GTiff 
         ${TESTDIR}/${INFILE}.TIF 
         ${TESTDIR}/${INFILE}_sub.tif
```

My results are below. The shapefile is displayed in the dotted red line, with the clip overlaid on the original.  Notice the grid offset produced by `gdalwarp`.  I've also run this on lower resolultion Landsat8 data with similar results (the ratio of the offset error is the same, i.e. ~20% in x, ~5% in y). 
This issue [QGIS clipper problem when mask used](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/143128/qgis-clipper-problem-when-mask-used) is similar except I am already using the `-tr` option.  Anyone know what's going on?  Is this a GDAL bug or a QGIS?

[image: Misalignment in clipped raster image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your cutline lines up perfectly with cell edges, the output raster will always be shifted/resampled to align with the polygon when that option is selected. If you leave the -crop_to_cutline option out, cells outside the masking layer just get converted to no-data in the output instead of being removed. I'm sure there's a way to get rid of those no-data cells in a subsequent step, but I tend to just do my raster work in GRASS instead, and avoid the problem entirely.

Comment: Accepted this answer over @xunilk because this can be implemented with the `Clipper` plugin in QGIS.

Answer (score 2):

It is preferable to use **gdal_translate** command. The syntax is:

```
gdal_translate -projwin xmin ymax xmax ymin input_raster output_raster
```

where **-projwin** parameter guarantees complete alignment.

To test my approach I used the raster and the clipper polygon of next image; where it can be observed that there is a complete misalignment between both layers. From into red rectangle area of Layer Properties Window, for clipper polygon, I got **xmin ymax xmax ymin** parameters.

[image]

In my case, the complete command was:

```
gdal_translate -projwin 355144.88 4473174.81 355826.88 4472712.24 /home/zeito/pyqgis_data/aleatorio.tif /home/zeito/pyqgis_data/my_output.tif
```

After running it in my bash console (Windows users can use OSGeo Console), I got:

[image]

where it can be observed a perfect alignment.

Comment: can you please tell us which version of GDAL you used to get this effect? I've had zero luck with 2.0.1 in a windows environment, the projwin tag always shifts the output cells a little.

Comment: It is gdal 1.10.1 in an stable Debian system.

Comment: thanks. I tried the same command in 1.11 and it worked perfectly, so the newer version's been broken. Infuriating!

Comment: The change in the latest versions of GDAL is intended. See this discussion:
http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-gdal-translate-with-projwin-possible-bug-td5278296.html

It might be nice if QGIS could implement a 'snap to pixels' checkbox for example, to allow the old behavior again.